# How to get the Place Object from autocompletePredictions in New Place SDK

Tags: android, google-places-api

I have integrated the new Place SDK provided by Google.

My Auto Completion method is given Below. How can I get the Place Object from the response?

```
private fun getPlaceAutoComplete(placesClient: PlacesClient, query: String) {
        val token = AutocompleteSessionToken.newInstance()
        val request = FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest.builder()
                .setSessionToken(token)
                .setQuery(query)
                .build()
        placesClient.findAutocompletePredictions(request).addOnSuccessListener { response ->
            placeList.clear()// Place List is a List of Place Instances
            for (prediction in response.autocompletePredictions) {

                var place = prediction.getPlace()// There is no option to ge the Place.
                placeList.add(place)
            }
            setAdapter(placeList)
        }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            if (exception is ApiException) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Place not found: " + exception.statusCode)
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Follow [This Official Sample](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-places-demos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AutoCompletePrediction` class has a [`getPlaceId()`](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/places/api/model/AutocompletePrediction.html#getPlaceId()) method for getting a [Place ID](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/place-id).

To retrieve the `Place` object itself, you must [Retrieve the place details using the place ID](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/place-id#place-details) by using a call to [`PlacesClient.fetchPlace()`](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/places/api/net/PlacesClient#fetchPlace(com.google.android.libraries.places.api.net.FetchPlaceRequest)). As per the [Migration guide](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration#fetch_a_place_by_id):

> Calls to `fetchPlace()` initiate a [Places Details SKU](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/usage-and-billing#places-details), the cost for which includes the request and any data fields belonging to the [Basic Data SKU](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/usage-and-billing#basic-data). You can also request [Contact Data](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/usage-and-billing#contact-data) and [Atmosphere Data](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/usage-and-billing#atmosphere-data) for an additional charge. See [Usage and Billing](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/usage-and-billing) for more details.

So you should generally avoid getting all of the Place details if cost is a concern.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is working. But do you know why placeLikelihood.place.id is returning null for nearest place list?